# How to get options in a form with values extracted from SQL database

Tags: cs50

```
<select class="form-control" name="symbol">
    <option disabled selected value="">Symbol</option>
    <? for each($symbols as $symbols): ?>
    <option value="<?=$symbol?>"><?=$symbol?></option>
    <? endforeach ?>
</select>
```

`$` symbols consists of data submitted by query (`SELECT....`) of cs50

Answer (score 0):

Almost, you were very close. It's: `foreach($symbols as $symbol)`

Also, it's a good idea to escape untrusted data before displaying it.
For this purpose, I'd suggest [`htmlentities(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) The exception, of course, is if you were already storing it escaped in the database. I'd advise against this practice, though, as it's easy for the database to wind-up in an inconsistent state, especially over a long period of time, over many revisions.

So, altogether, that would be:

```
<select class="form-control" name="symbol">
   <option disabled selected value="">Symbol</option>
   <? foreach($symbols as $symbol): ?>
   <option value="<?=htmlentities($symbol)?>"><?=htmlentities($symbol)?></option>
   <? endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion